# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'TensorFlowLinearClassifier'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to Neural Networks and TensorFlow and have encountered the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'TensorFlowLinearClassifier'
```

and this warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
iris=datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target,classifier.predict(iris.data))
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

I have already gone through similar answers on this site but they were not satisfactory. Please help in removing this error and warning.

Answer (score 1):

from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base is deprecated therefore to use linear classifer do the following:

1. Replace tensorflow.contrib.learn with tensorflow.estimator
2. Change TensorFlowLinearClassifier() to LinearClassifier(feature_columns)

where feature_columns: An iterable containing all the feature columns used by the model. All items in the set should be instances of classes derived from FeatureColumn.

Check this [Tensorflow Documention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier) ,[Deprecated message and Fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/README.md)

Comment: I did that but it is giving a new error that `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'`

Comment: Also its `tensorflow.contrib.learn` not `tf.contrib.learn` and if i replace it with `tensorflow.estimator` or `tf.estimator` gives error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.estimator'` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'` respectively

Comment: yeah it is 'tensorflow' and not 'tf'.  which version of tensorflow is installed?

Comment: It is the latest version of tensorflow. I upgraded it last night using pip

Comment: TensorFlow version is 1.7.0.

Comment: try restarting your terminal if this issue still persists then open an issue on the tensorflow repository on GitHub

Comment: Will try Thanks

Comment: Are you getting this error    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'